# Presenting just a subset of emojis on the keyboard on iOS apps

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji

I am making an app where I use the "People" emojis as avatar faces and the "Food and drink" emojis for, well, food and drink icons. I would like to use the regular keyboard for presenting the emojis for user input, but I would like to present only these two categories of emojis (and even so, each category would be presented in a different context).

I am working with iOS 8, Xcode 6.3 and Swift.

Can I configure the regular keyboard so that it only shows a subset of emojis which I define?

If not, can I create a new custom keyboard preserving everything from the original Apple keyboard but limiting the subset of characters? Any pointers on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not configure the regular keyboard so that it only shows a subset of emojis. But yes can make your own custom keyboard.

You can find some really good posts about how to make the custom keyboards:

- http://verisage.us/en/blog/2014/07/17/ios-8-custom-keyboard-swift-tutorial/
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-creating-a-custom-keyboard-in-swift--cms-22344

Also I found this FaceBoardPlus sample: http://code4app.net/ios/FaceBoardPlus/52a9ba56cb7e841e178b69d0 which is exactly what you are looking for but written in objective c.

**EDIT:** [From iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html):

> After a user chooses a custom keyboard, it becomes the keyboard for
>   every app the user opens. For this reason, a keyboard you create must,
>   at minimum, provide certain base features. Most important, your
>   keyboard must allow the user to switch to another keyboard.
>
> To provide a fully custom keyboard for just your app or to supplement
>   the system keyboard with custom keys in just your app, the iOS SDK
>   provides other, better options. Read about custom input views and
>   input accessory views in [Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12) in [Text
>   Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html).

Comment: Hi Ajay. The three links are great, very good material. Do you know if i can use the standard iOS keyboards as a base and just modify it or do I have to create a keyboard view completely from scratch?

Comment: I think input accessory views are better suited to what I want to do than a custom keyboard. Thanks for pointing this out!